# stop a user from being able to paste, but allow paste values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have the below code in my workbook, which stops a user from being able to paste anything at all.

My needs have now changed and i want to be able to let  user paste values only.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.OnKey "^c"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
 Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.OnKey "^c"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Copying and Pasting into the skills matrix has been disabled to prevent changes in the workbook functionality."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This VBA code should do that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it kinda works, its a bit weird tho, it pastes on the first mouse click in a new cell

Comment: You may also without VBA [protect only the format](https://excel.tips.net/T003515_Protecting_a_Worksheets_Format.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my previous answer, would this work?

So we check if something is pasted, then save the value, undo the paste and reinsert the value only.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UndoList As String, StoreValue As String
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then
    StoreValue = Target.Value
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
    End With
    Target.Value = StoreValue
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If the suggestion in the comments isn't a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that I tried successfully could be this:

Hijack CTRL+C and CTRL+V, make it only paste special values.

So, by using your original workbook code, but replace

```vb
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
```

with

```vb
Application.OnKey "^{v}", "pasteValues"
Application.OnKey "^{c}", "copyValues"
```

Then make a module with the following:

```vb
Public copyVal As String
Private Sub pasteValues()
selection = copyVal
End Sub
Private Sub copyValues()
copyVal = selection
End Sub
```

And now you can copy and paste, but it will only move the value.